# on cascade delete on many to many relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I had used many to many relationship.i have three table named:product,tag,productstag. in here I want whenever I am going to delete a product it will also delete the relationship it had on productstag table.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('productstags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->integer('tag_id');
        $table->primary(['product_id','tag_id']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

as you can see I have used product_id and tag_id as the primary key.
so I can't use this

```php
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
```

so what's the alternative?

on my product model

```
 public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag','productstags','product_id','tag_id')->withTimestamps();


}
```

on my tag model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','Productstags','tag_id','product_id');

}
```

on my produduct destroy function:

```
public function destroy(Request $request,$id)
{
    $product=Product::findOrFail($id);
    if($request->file('image')==''){
        $input=$request->except('photo_id');
    }
    else{
        $input=$request->all();
        unlink(public_path()."/images/".$product->image->name);

    }

    $product->delete($input);
    Session::flash('deleted_user','the user has been deleted');

    return  redirect(route('product.index'));

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason `product_id` and `tag_id` are `primary key`?

Comment: yes! @AlbertoGuilherme

Answer (score 0):

It's not as pretty as `cascade` but you could override the delete method and do this:

```
public function delete(){
    $this->name_of_the_relationship()->delete();
    return parent::delete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i  have put that function on my productstags migration table. but still when i am deleting a product it not not deleting from productstags table. where should i put that function?

Comment: @JubayerAhmed - that function goes on the Product `model`. The class that has the relationship

Comment: i don't have a productstags model neither function. as i mentioned before it's many to many relationship ! i migrate the table .productstags is the pivot tabel.

Comment: @JubayerAhmed What models do you have? How do you call the `delete` function?

Comment: i have Product model and Tag model. productstags is the pivot table. on product model i have tags function. when i am deleting a products it delete it through ProductController@destroy menthod.

Comment: @JubayerAhmed - You will put the function on the *Product* Model if you want to delete the relationship on the delete of a product. And , if you want to delete with the deletion of the tag, You'll have to add a tag function to the *Tag* model and add the delete function there too.

Comment: sorry to disappoint you bro! it's not deleting the pivot table data :/

Comment: i don't have a model for pivot table. as i told you before i have used many to many relationship

Comment: @JubayerAhmed - Post the **PRODUCT** and **TAG** model and the destroy code please